# CSS for content alignment

Tags: css, html

I have a div tag with fixed width and height and I want another div tag positioned at the exact center of the parent div. I have tried margin=auto but it doesn't solve the problem. Any pointers? Thanks

Comment: Could you please show us your current markup and CSS, and be explicit about the changes you've tried so far?

Comment: horizontal center is easy with margin-left and margin-right set to auto, but I dont think there is a way to vertically center a div without using javascript

Comment: @box86rowh vertical-align:middle with inline-block :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe6S6/1/))

```
div.outer {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background: blue;
}

div.inner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red
    display: inline-block;
}
```